# Why Sybase ASE does a table scan when not materialized computed column is added

Tags: database, sap-ase, calculated-columns

When I add not materialized computed column to a table, ASE decided to copy whole table, when actual content of the datapages is not affected.

Example:

```
create table t (i int null)
go
set showplan on
go
alter table t
add c compute (i+1) not materialized
go

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 1 (at line 1).
...
       |   |INSERT Operator (VA = 1)
...
       |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)
       |   |   |  FROM TABLE
       |   |   |  t
       |   |   |  Table Scan.
...
       |   |  TO TABLE
       |   |  #syb__altab
...
```

if you check pages content with `dbcc page` you may see that the old and new pages are identical

1. Why ASE does this useless operation?
2. Is it possible to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it does that because not materialized computer columns may result in different values each time you access it. So in order to make sure of the data integrity and each cell has data that should be there, it first copies it into a location then it uses it to perform a fucnction that you ask it to do.

Comment: it does not seem to be so, at least, I tried to create computed column which divide column1 by column2 with zero values on column2, and the comp.column was successfully created, the error was rised only when I did a select, what means it do not compute any values while adds a comp.column, if it does not compute it cannot do any integrity checks. i suppose it's just a silly design - it copy table every time new column added what ever it is materialized or not